# Simple Java project osgi bundle built under the JBoss Studio would not run in Fuse

Tags: maven, jboss, osgi, bundle, jbossfuse

I used com.fazecast.jSerialCom-1.3.9.jar to build a serial com java project to process the data in-out from the regular com port. It seems to be very common java project. The pure Java jar of the project witll run independently.  Somehow,  as needed I put it into part of dependency of my maven project pom.xml and configured part of the my plugin, then building the OSGI bundle will generated an error within Fuse operation.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <instructions>
                  <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                 <!--  <Import-Package>*,!com.fazecast.jSerialComm</Import-Package>  -->
                  <Embed-Dependency>jSerialComm</Embed-Dependency>
               </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I used com.fazecast.jSerialCom-1.3.9.jar to build a serial com java project to process the data in-out from the regular com port. It seems to be very common java project. The pure Java jar of the project witll run independently.  Somehow,  as needed I put it into part of dependency of my maven project pom.xml and configured part of the my plugin, then building the OSGI bundle will generated an error within Fuse operation.

Comment: If the project generates "an error" then you have to change "something". This is probably the best answer you will get. You have to be more specific. What is the exact error? One thing that looks strange is the executions part. I would try to leave that out. Also make sure you project is of packaging bundle.

Comment: When I started the bundle I got: Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
 Unable to start bundle 278: Unresolved constraint in bundle camel-mode1-interface [278]: Unable to resolve 278.1: missing requirement [278.1] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.fazecast.jSerialComm)

Comment: I removed the <executions>.. </executions> and add the <Impor-Package>..</Import-Package> back, not the error point to : Unable to start bundle 278: Unresolved constraint in bundle camel-mode1-interface [278]: Unable to resolve 278.2: missing requirement [278.2] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.lang3)(version>=3.4.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
however, the pom.xml does have the <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.4</version>
  </dependency>   I am confused with <version>>= 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

That looks good. You will need to install additioanal transitive dependencies separately.

In OSGi the compile depdencies and runtime dependencies are handled separately. Most of your needed dependencies will already be present as OSGi bundles in maven central.

So just install the commons-lang3 using the mvn:groupId/artifactId/version syntax as a bundle.

Comment: Here was my lack of knowledge of the proper way to add the commons-lang3.  when i tried to install it as a features, it failed, so just used "install .." as an osgi bundle, it worked.  why?  In addition, why I just need to Import-Package for !com.fazecast.jSerialComm  only, while I do not need to configure other dependency as same way?

Comment: Installing a bundle using a feature or using install -s should work in the same way. If the dependency is a bundle then you usually do not need to do anything special at build time. You just let the maven bundle plugin create the Import-Package statements. If it is no bundle then you can embed it as you did in your config.
Btw. jSerialComm seems to load native libs .. this might require additional work .. not sure though. 
The best solution generally is to use only bundles. Especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: I tried to repeat the process on another server with same ./m2 depository and same project but without internet connectivity.  Somehow, the same install mvn:groupid/artifactid/version won;t install, the error from fuse console indicated "Errors executing command: error installing bundle..", something of configuration of that fuse server is missing?

Comment: You should place the m2 repo at the default localtion homedirectory/.m2/repository. Then it should work.

Comment: the .m2 is under the homedirectory of that server.   but still failed to install.  I even had the same error about to install my project bundle on this server, while the same project could be installed on my other machine (internet connected one).

Comment: Strange.. have you tried with a plain karaf 4.0.3? The Fuse karaf is a bit older I guess.

Comment: After I successed to install commons-lang3 in fuse console, I tried to repeated with jSerialComm same proces, instead of configuring it as in plugin above (removed all <configuration>..).  But I got the "Unresolved constraint .., missing requirement" error from starting my project, after I installed the jSerialComm (install mvn:com.fazecast/jSerialcom/1.3.9)  which is in ~/.m2/repository/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/1.3.9.  The commons-lang was installed (mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/version). I am little  confused why commons-lang3 was OK , but no jSerialComm.

Comment: You can not install jSerialComm like this as it is no bundle. So embedding it like you did is a good idea. Be careful though that this still does not guarantee that it will really work in OSGi.